# Adding crashlytics in an Android project without Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I'm working with an Android Project which does not have Gradle. It is an old-style structure project which has not been updated for using Gradle.

I'm trying to find the way of adding Crashlytics but I cannot find a way.

Is there any easy way to add crashlytics without Gradle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Android Studio?

All the ways you can integrate are listed on [Fabric's download page](https://fabric.io/downloads)

Comment: That works perfectly with Gradle, however this project does not have Gradle and also I cannot find the way to get the AAR library.

Comment: Yeah on the downloads page it gives you different IDEs and build tools to choose from (not just Android Studio)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using gradle, I guess it's still a Eclipse project. And Crashlytics is now part of Fabric, so I guess it's Fabric too what you are using.

About Eclipse, I'd recommend migrating it to Android Studio and take advantage of Gradle, but anyway, the steps would be:

- Clip on Help -> Install New Software
- Click "Add..." and add a new repository with the name Fabric and in the location, type in https://fabric.io/download/eclipse.
- Look for "Fabric" and check its checkbox
- Install it, restart eclipse, and you should be seeing a new blue icon in Eclipse's toolbar, for Fabric.

Edit: for using the library files (jar and aar) directly, in a IDE independent way, or with maven, the artifactory repo for twitter can be useful: https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/webapp/home.html?3

There, you can find crashlytics libraries: http://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/webapp/search/artifact/?4&q=crashlytics, and also fabric: http://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/webapp/search/artifact/?5&q=fabric

For every dependency, Twitter's Artifactory help with code for Ivy, Maven or Gradle integration.

Comment: We use Android Studio but still keeping the old-fashion structure of eclipse. That plugin is prepared for working on Gradle which this project does not have.

Comment: Oh, if you need the aar to handle it manually I guess accessing the Maven repo for Crashlytics can be good:

https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/repo/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/

(specifically: https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/repo/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics/2.2.4/crashlytics-2.2.4.aar)